# Devise logout not working

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm using the latest version of devise and rails 4.2.4. 
I've my home page

```
 public/index.html
```

which contains heavy javascript. But when I load it from some other page, it doesn't load with all the effects. So included

```
 $(document).on('page:load', ready);
 <script src="/js/modernizr-2.6.2.min.js"></script>
 <script src="/js/main.js"></script>
```

in application.js file.
But then 
Logout

```
<%= link_to "Logout",destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete %>
```

doesn't work! It gets rendered as GET /users/sign_out.

When I remove those links from application.js, it works fine.

Any workaround for this issue?

Comment: question: if you're using rails, why is your homepage in public and not a rails template of some kind?

Comment: @TarynEast Well, I tried to include inside the app but some effects went missing.

Comment: Yes but you shouldn't need to include it in that way - if you're doing a standard rails application should be an erb template instead.

Comment: ok, just realised that half your code was invisible due to markdown formatting. ;) note: use > for quotes. use four spaces of indentation for code.

Comment: But if I include in the form of an erb template, some of the scripts were not loading. Does this have something to do with my issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your javascript has an error in it.

--

Each time you use `method: :delete` or `method: :patch`, Rails populates a form with the appropriate verb, [using Javascript](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/link_to) to set it correctly:

> [link_to] dynamically creates an HTML form and immediately submit the form for processing using the HTTP verb specified. Useful for having links perform a POST operation in dangerous actions like deleting a record (which search bots can follow while spidering your site). Supported verbs are :post, :delete, :patch, and :put. **Note that if the user has JavaScript disabled, the request will fall back to using GET**

The above is true if your javascript is broken (IE you have an error preventing it from working properly on the page).

--

Since you haven't posted your JS, I cannot give you any specifics.

However, I *can* say that your JS should be as [unobtrusive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript) as possible.

Using `<script>` anywhere in your Rails app is bad practice; you should have the files concatenated in your `application.js` with the help of [sprockets manifest directives](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#manifest-files-and-directives):

```
#app/assets/javascripts/application.js
//= require main
//= require modernizr
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that most browsers do not support the DELETE method, the request will actually be submitted as GET, with a `data-method="delete"` attribute. This relies on the "Unobtrusive scripting adapter for jQuery" (jquery-ujs) being loaded by your page.

If you were using the standard rails templates, the 'application.js' manifest file would take care of that for you, but given that you are putting your index.html in the public directory you will have to manually include both `jquery` and `jquery-ujs` in your header.

An alternative is to change the route to logout to actually use GET (you will anyway have issues with the PUT and PATCH methods as well), adding this to your devise config (from [devise wiki](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Add-sign_in,-sign_out,-and-sign_up-links-to-your-layout-template)):

```
# config/initializers/devise.rb
# The default HTTP method used to sign out a resource. Default is :delete.
config.sign_out_via = :get
```

If you plan to use rails you should find out why you are having issues with the standard rails way of dealing with view templates. I use a lot of javascript-heavy pages, and they work just fine. Plus you get all the benefits of the asset pipeline.

Comment: I'm aware of hanging in devise.rb, but I don't want to get along with a GET method. Thanks!

Comment: I think that if you use `GET` for log out then browser prefetching and users who embed the log out URL in an `<img>` tag can log out the users unexpectedly.